# Mostrar texto cuando se hace en hover en una imagen

Tags: html, css

Tengo el código:

```css
.desvanecer:hover {
  opacity: 0.07;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -o-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -ms-transition: opacity 500ms;
  transition: opacity 500ms;
}
```

```html
<img class="desvanecer" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCYnU.png" />
```

con esto logro desvanecer la imagen al pasar el mouse, pero ¿cómo se hace para que aparezca información adicional sobre la imagen desvanecida? Es decir que sobre la imagen desvanecida diga algo como ejemplo: "Hola, esta es la información del logo".

Ejemplo:

[image: La imagen se torna gris y se ubica texto por encima]

Quisiera conocer lo mas básico para lograrlo.

Comment: quisiera conocer lo mas basico para lograr la pregunta, solo veo mucho codigo y no se que es bootstrap, gracias por atender la pregunta..

Comment: No creo que sea un duplicado porque solo parece requerirse texto sin necesidad de JS o bibliotecas de ningún tipo. Pero deberías aclarar al menos cómo la solución de Omar no te vale, para que tengamos una idea mejor de lo que quieres

Comment: mas especifico.. www.dribbble.com pasa el mouse sobre el trabajo que muetran.. gracias..

Comment: aldanux.. eso es exactamente lo que busco.. ahora lo estudiare.. muchas gracias..

Comment: Nosotros no somos adivinos y no podemos saber exactamente lo que buscas a no ser que nos lo digas (mediante texto o una imagen). Por favor, describe mejor lo que buscas, ayúdanos a ayudarte

Comment: @Rick - edité la pregunta en base a tus comentarios. Por favor ten en cuenta a futuro que las preguntas deben estar lo más claras posibles, especificando exactamente lo que se busca y (si los hay) qué errores puntuales aparecen y dónde. Más información en [ask]

Comment: @aldanux - por el comentario del autor, quizás deberías publicar como respuesta para que la acepte.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Cómo funciona el ejemplo que enlazas**

Si miras el código, puedes ver que lo que hace [Dribble](https://dribbble.com/) es que cada "tarjeta" tiene diferentes contenedores y elementos dentro de un `div` (simplificando): uno contiene la imagen, otro contiene el texto con la descripción, otro las opciones, y otro el autor.

El `div` que contiene la descripción de la imagen (`.dribbble-over`) tiene por defecto opacidad de 0 (por lo que está invisible), y cuando se pasa el ratón por encima del contenedor de la imagen (`.dribbble-img`), se cambia su opacidad a 1. Todo hecho con CSS y transiciones CSS (sin necesidad de usar JavaScript).

**Cómo adaptar ese ejemplo a tu código**

El código que compartes en la pregunta funciona de la manera contraria: cuando se pasa el ratón por encima de la imagen, ésta pierde opacidad haciéndose casi invisible. Pero eso no es un problema, sólo cambiará un poco el funcionamiento.

Lo que debes hacer:

- Crear un contenedor (un `div`) que tendrá dentro la imagen.
- Crear dentro del mismo un nuevo contenedor para poner el texto que se mostrará.
- Posicionar este último contenedor de manera absoluta y que quede detrás de la imagen (con un `z-index` negativo o menor que el de la imagen)

Aquí dejo un ejemplo simple de cómo podría ser:

```css
.div-imagen {
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
}

.div-imagen > div {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  z-index:-1;
  padding:10px;
  margin:0;
}

.desvanecer:hover {
  opacity: 0.07;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -o-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -ms-transition: opacity 500ms;
  transition: opacity 500ms;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-imagen">
  <div>
      Descripción de la foto que quieres que se muestre
  </div>
  <img class="desvanecer" src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
</div>
```

Comment: muchas gracias.. y a todos por su paciencia... he aprendido algo gracias a todos

Answer (score 7):

Ejemplos como se podría realizar el efecto (solo **CSS**):

> Mostrar texto cuando se hace en hover en una imagen

**#1:** con `line-height`:

```css
.img-container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative; 
}

.img-container p {
  margin: auto;  
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  
  line-height: 200px; /* igual height de la imagen */
  
  background: #000;
  transition: opacity .4s linear;
  cursor: pointer;  
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

.img-container:hover p {
  opacity: .75;  
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200">
    <p>Texto de prueba</p>
</div>
```

**#2:** con `padding`:

```css
.img-container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 0;
}

.img-container p {  
  height: 0;
  margin: 0;
  
  padding: 100px 0; /* == mitad de la imagen (height) */
  
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;  
  background: #000;
  transition: opacity .4s linear;
  cursor: pointer;  
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

.img-container:hover p {
  opacity: .75;  
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200">
  <p>Texto de prueba</p>
</div>
```

**#3:** con efecto `slide-up` texto:

```css
.img-container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.img-container:before {
  content: '';
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  background: #000;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .3s linear;   
}

.img-container:hover:before { 
  opacity: .75;
}

.img-container p {
  width: inherit;  
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%; 
  transition: top .3s linear;
}

.img-container:hover p {    
  top: 70%;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200">
  <p>Texto de prueba</p>
</div>
```

**#4:** similar al ejemplo de la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```css
body {
  background: #eee;
}

.img-container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 10px 10px 30px 10px;
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.img-container:before {
  content: '';
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .1s ease-out;   
}

.img-container:hover:before { 
  opacity: 1;
}

.img-container .text-container {
  width: inherit;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  color: #444;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%; 
}

.img-container:hover .text-container {    
  top: 0;
}

p {
  color: #888;
  font-size: .75em;
  line-height: .2em;
}

i {
  font-style: normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x150">
  <div class="text-container">
    <h4>Titulo</h4>
    <p>Texto de prueba</p>
    <p>Texto de prueba</p>
  </div>
  <i>icons | icons | icons |<i/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

No es una ardua tarea de realizar, leyendo un poco lo consiguías.

Pasos:

1. Encerrar la imagen en un `figure`
2. Añadir también un `<figcaption>` con la descripción de la imagen

```js
let image = document.querySelector('.image');
let select = document.getElementById('effect');

select.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
  image.className = `image ${this.value}`;
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo');

.image {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  height: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 15px auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
}

figure img {
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all .23s ease;
  width: 100%;
}

.image figcaption {
  color: #555;
  font-family: 'Exo';
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  line-height: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  top: 0;
  transition: all .23s ease;
  width: 100%;
}

.image.fade figcaption {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.image.push figcaption {
  top: 0;
  transform: translateY(250px);
}

.image.push:hover > img {
  transform: translateY(-250px);
}

.image.push:hover > figcaption {
  transform: translateY(0px);
}

.image.fade:hover > img {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.image.fade:hover > figcaption {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

/* Form styles */
form {
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 150px;
}

form label {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', 'Open Sans';
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

form select {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', 'Open Sans';
  margin: 0 0 0 10px;
  padding: 0 1rem;
}
```

```html
<figure class="image fade">
  <img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-KcxlSXC0qk8/TeKSFXmSAjI/AAAAAAAAAS8/cYqGQolvNbs/s1600/3musicos.jpg">
  <figcaption>Los tres músicos</figcaption>
</figure>

<form>
  <label for="effect">Effect</label>
  <select id="effect">
    <option value="fade">Fade</option>
    <option value="push">Push</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Hola Mariano, creo que el OP fue claro en su objetivo, al menos para mí, queda claro. Por otro lado no iba a contestar, es más, voté por duplicado, pero @AlvaroMontoro, autor de la respuesta de la pregunta de referencia, aclaró que no podría tratarse de un duplicado, por lo que escribí ésto. Saludos y gracias por las recomendaciones, las tendré en cuenta en la próxima oportunidad.

Comment: +1 a esta buena respuesta

Answer (score 3):

Tal vez utilizando el atributo *title* logres lo que deseas:

```
<img class="desvanecer" src="logo.png" title="Hola, esta es la información del logo." />
```

Comment: gracias omar, pero no es lo que buscaba.. gracias por atender..

Comment: @Rick ¿qué es lo que quieres que se muestre? ¿Y cómo no es esto lo que buscas? Si es solo texto y no quieres usar JavaScript, `title` es una buena opción

Comment: Tal vez lo que quieres hacer es un Tooltip, échale un ojo a este enlace: http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_tooltip.asp

Answer (score 1):

si no deseas usar frameworks te propongo las siguiente solución:

Usar un div contenedor de la imagen y un div hermando de la imagen donde se guarda la descripción del evento hover.

luego capturar el evento hover para el div padre, para ocultar y mover el div de la descripción con css y jquery.

otra opción es usar [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) para realizar los efectos de movimiento.

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div class="contenedorImg">    
    <img  src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" />
    <div class="contenedorDescripcion">Contenido de la descripción</div> 
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body{
  margin: 0;
}
.contenedorImg{
  width: 400px;
}
.contenedorDescripcion {   
   color : #FFF;
   width: 400px;
   height: 200px;
   position: absolute;
   top:200px;
   left:0;
   background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
   visibility: hidden;
   transition:  top 0.5s;
   }

   .muestraDescripcion{
     top: 0 !important;
   }

   .hidden{
       visibility: hidden !important;
   }
   .visible{
       visibility: visible !important;
   }
```

Javascript (JQuery)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".contenedorImg").hover(
    function(){

        $(".contenedorDescripcion").addClass("visible muestraDescripcion");
    },
    function(){

    $(".contenedorDescripcion").removeClass("muestraDescripcion");
    setTimeout(
        function(){ 
        $(".contenedorDescripcion").removeClass("visible muestraDescripcion"); 
        $(".contenedorDescripcion").addClass("hidden");
        }, 300);
    }
    );
});
```

Revisa el ejemplo andando, el mouseleave al bajar el div se puede comportar un poco raro, pero basta con un poco de más codigo js!
https://jsfiddle.net/camilocalderont/svg9ho0m/