# ¿Cómo hacer efecto hover en imágenes con Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css

Tengo ese efecto hover en imagenes pero quiero saber como lo puedo hacer con bootstrap sin tener que utilizar Background-image.

```css
#effect-hover .img {
  background-image: url(http://noticias.universia.cl/net/images/educacion/c/cu/cur/cursos-online-gratuitos-programar-java.jpg);
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

#effect-hover #efecto {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: rgb(190, 180, 9, 0.8);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 2s;
}

#effect-hover .img:hover #efecto {
  opacity: 1;
}

#effect-hover h2 {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 30px;
  transition-duration: 2s
}

#effect-hover .img:hover h2 {
  top: 15px;
}

#effect-hover p {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 30px;
  transition-duration: 2s
}

#effect-hover .img:hover p {
  bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<section id="effect-hover">
  <div class="img">
    <div id="efecto">
      <h2>Efecto</h2>
      <p>lorem ipsum atsais dase.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Exactamente que quieres lograr?

Comment: Queria saber como puedo hacer ese mismo efecto sin utilizar Background-img. luego como meterlo en una columna en bootstrap

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Efecto Hover con imágenes y texto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/13872/efecto-hover-con-im%c3%a1genes-y-texto) y [Mostrar texto cuando se hace en hover en una imagen](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/44058/6491)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te dejo el código funcional como lo pides, para incorporar **Bootstrap** solo debes ir conociendo poco a poco las clases que se usan en algunas situaciones...si tienes dudas con gusto las respondo.

```css
#effect-hover .img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-size: cover;
    margin: 20px auto;
    position: relative;
}

#effect-hover #efecto {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: rgba(190, 180, 9, 0.8);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 2s;
}

#effect-hover .img:hover #efecto {
  opacity: 1;
}

#effect-hover h2 {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 30px;
  transition-duration: 2s;
  margin: 0px;
}

#effect-hover .img:hover h2 {
  top: 50px;
}

#effect-hover p {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 30px;
  transition-duration: 2s;
  margin: 0px;
}

#effect-hover .img:hover p {
  bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col-lg-5 col-md-7 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
  <div id="effect-hover">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="http://noticias.universia.cl/net/images/educacion/c/cu/cur/cursos-online-gratuitos-programar-java.jpg" class="img-fluid">
      <div id="efecto">
        <h2>Efecto</h2>
        <p>lorem ipsum atsais dase.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </sectdivion>
</div>
```

Comment: tengo otra duda, al momento que la hago responsive el efecto se sale de la imagen. Como puedo hacer para que se haga responsive tambien el efecto?

Comment: @JOGUELCB una forma es cambiar los valores de las columnas de bootstrap (ya te edité la pregunta) ... si lo que quieres es hacer algo más "personalizado" según la resolución de pantalla entonces es necesario usar media Queries

Comment: si, ya te entiendo creo que tampoco me funcionaba porque no me habia percatado de que estas utilizando la cdn de Bootstrap 3.3.7 y yo estoy ocupando Bootstrap 4 alpha

Comment: @JOGUELCB esos detalles debes aclararlos en la pregunta, igual no cambia mucho las versiones la única clase que cambia considerablemente es img-responsive a img-fluid, te he editado la respuesta con bootstrap 4!

Comment: otra pregunta, porque al momento de cambiar la imagen el efecto no es lo mismo? osea se cuando veo los responsive  el efecto se sale de la imagen? PD:disculpa tanta ignorancia.

Comment: @JOGUELCB para ajustar de forma más personalizada el efecto según la resolución son necesarias media queries, creo que la única resolución que necesita una personalización es móvil por que en las otras 3 (que yo las probé) todo funcionaba correctamente